# Schematic "app" not found in collection "@nrwl/workspace"

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

Am I missing something here, I am trying to create a sample app using nx and I am getting below error

C:\Tryout\nxtryout\ibe20>*ng g app mobile-app*
*Schematic "app" not found in collection "@nrwl/workspace".
Error: Schematic "app" not found in collection "@nrwl/workspace".
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (C:\Tryout\nxtryout\ibe20\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:232:23)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (C:\Tryout\nxtryout\ibe20\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:69:29)
    at GenerateCommand.getSchematic (C:\Tryout\nxtryout\ibe20\node_modules@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:137:27)
    at GenerateCommand.initialize (C:\Tryout\nxtryout\ibe20\node_modules@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:45:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)*

Comment: I need to add ng add @nrwl/nest, it started working after adding this.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. @Rafeeq. However, I was not prompted to answer a few setup questions as exptected accordingly to https://github.com/onehungrymind/angular-core-workshop